# jqplot pie chart legend width

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm trying to render the legend of a pie chart so that it has a fixed width, and when the labels reach that width (the div holder) to hyphenate on the next line. I tried the row option but it doesn't work very well because my data is dynamic and at times i have say 3 data sets, and each one of them gets rendered in a separate row, while at other times i have 15-20 data sets and it becomes messy.

Anyway the solution is to restrain the legend to the width of the div, that it is rendered into, yet it doesn't seem to be accepting any css alterations. I tried adding width:250px; to the "jqplot-table-legend" in jqPlot css, i also tried adding it into various places using Inspect Element in Chrome to test whether it works, but it doesn't seem to accept the new width. I also tried to hard code it into the javascript file at various places with no luck.

I'm not sure what I can add to the question in terms of code. Everything is pretty standard on the jqPlot side.

Any suggestions on how to get around this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like the quick and dirty way, but it gets the job done. I'll use the jqplot.pieRenderer.js file as the example since it's easier to read than the minified version. Open the js file and scroll down to line 568. Right under

```
this._elem = $(document.createElement('table'));
this._elem.addClass('jqplot-table-legend');
```

add

```
this._elem.css({width: 300});
```

That will stretch the table out to whatever width you need it to be. Unfortunately, it also stretches out the column with the color swatch so you'll now need to scroll down a little further until you find

```
td1.css({textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: rs});
```

change that to

```
td1.css({width: 16, textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: rs});
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: Hello Mike, that seems to be the right answer to the pie renderer, I've changed it since then to Donut sadly. I tried your answer and hard code it within `this._elem = $('<table class="jqplot-table-legend" style="width:250px'+ss+'"></table>');` by adding the width there, but it doesn't seem to be enough. Do you have a tip on the donut too? I'll accept the above answer tho.

Comment: I made the legend 250px but the problem is that every label is on a new line, and i can't make them float next to each other.

Comment: ok so the solution that i came up with was to put the `<tr class="jqplot-table-legend"></tr>` into a div container and float it to the left, which is enough as a solution to the problem. Thanks for the tips, they were a great guide were to look for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:
Just add these lines:

```
if (this.width) {
    ss['width'] = this.width;
}
```

They allow you to set an arbitrary width in each different graph

You might also want to add these lines in jquery.jqplot.js (i.e if rendering bars)
Search for "createElement('table')" as described by mike

Worked for me